# Python - Pandas error when splitting text using a function

Tags: python, pandas, function

I am trying to create a function that splits text in a column of a dataframe and puts each half of the split into a different new column. I want to split the text right after a specific phrase (defined as "search_text" in the function "create_var") and then trim that text to a specified number of characters (defined as left_trim_number in the function). My function has worked in some cases but does not work in others.

Here is the basic structure of my dataframe, where "lst" is my list of text items and "cols" are the two columns of the original dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
cols = ['page', 'text_i']
df1 = pd.DataFrame(lst, columns=cols)
```

Here is my function:

```
def create_var(varname, search_text, left_trim_number):
    df1[['a',varname]] = df1['text_i'].str.split(search_text, expand=True)
    df1[varname] = df1[varname].str[: left_trim_number ] 

create_var('var1','I am looking for the text that follows this ',3)
```

In the cases where it doesnt work, I get this error (which I assume is related to pandas):

*"ValueError: Columns must be same length as key"*

Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: You are getting the error when `split` returns a list of any length other than 2. For example, if `search_text` is `"hello"`, then `"hello world".split(search_text)` will return 2 elements (the correct length to fit in `df[['a', varname]]`). But, `"a".split(search_text)` will only return 1 element. Pandas then tries to fit one element into 2 columns, but can't, hence the `ValueError`

Comment: Please provide the entire error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"text":["hello world", "a", "again hello world"]})
search_text = "hello "


parts = df['text'].str.partition(search_text)
df['a'] = parts[0] + parts[1]
df['var1'] = parts[2]
df['var1'] = df['var1'].str[:3]
```

print(df)

Output:

```
                text             a var1
0        hello world        hello   wor
1                  a             a     
2  again hello world  again hello   wor
```

Comment: Thank you! I I reworked the function using str.partition and it works great now.